# Stack overflow in custom event processing

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I've tried to put on a very simple JAVA example (i'm a newbie) to handle events; it's a game skeleton (say chess, with two players, white and black)
Here is the source code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
// Game.java

package chess;

public class Game {

    private static Player p1;
    private static Player p2;
    private static Board b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b = new Board();
        p1 = new Player(b, "white");
        p2 = new Player(b, "black");

        p1.MakeMove();
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
// Board.java

package chess;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Board {

    int num;
    private ArrayList<NextMoveListener> listeners = new ArrayList<NextMoveListener>();

    public Board() {
        num = 0;
    }

    public void addListener(NextMoveListener nml) {
        listeners.add(nml);
    }

    void LastMove() {
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
    }

    void NextMove(NextMoveEvent e) {
        if (e.finished) {
            LastMove();
        } else {
            for (NextMoveListener nml : listeners) {
                if (nml != e.getSource()) {
                    nml.MakeMove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
// Player.java

package chess;

interface NextMoveListener {
    public void MakeMove();
}

public class Player implements NextMoveListener {

    private String name;
    private Board b;
    private int nMove;
    private NextMoveEvent evt;

    Player(Board b, String nome) {
        this.nMove = 0;
        this.b = b;
        this.name = nome;
        this.evt = new NextMoveEvent(this);
        b.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void MakeMove() {
        System.out.println("Player: " + name + ", move: " + (++nMove));
        evt.setFinished(nMove == 1000);
        b.NextMove(evt);
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
// NextMoveEvent.java

package chess;

import java.util.EventObject;

public class NextMoveEvent extends EventObject {

    boolean finished;

    public NextMoveEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public void setFinished(boolean finished) {
        this.finished = finished;
    }
}
```

Obviously there's no real game inside, it's just an example for exchanging events between the two players; it works fine with approximately 1000 moves per player; if I increase that number I get a stack overflow error.
I can't see my mistake! It seems to me not reserving any space on stack when calling MakeMove() method but still it crashes.

Comment: Unless it is inlined, a function call always takes room on the stack. At a minimum, the return address must be saved. You need to decouple your next move from being called within the event handler.

Comment: It seems that you really need to increase the stack size if you want handle larger amount of moves. Use `-Xss` jvm argument to increase the stack size. Your `makeMove` and `nextMove` is kind of a circular dependent until it reaches 1000 stack frames, so you should definitely think about increasing the stack limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call one method from inside another method, Java needs to keep track of the state of the first method until the second one has returned. So, if A calls B which calls C, I have a "stack" of methods A > B > C whose state I need to remember.

Java has a limited space for how many layers of nested methods it allows. So, if you get too deep into nesting methods like this, an exception (stack overflow) happens.

One solution is to change your recursive approach into a loop. Have `Player.MakeMove()` return a `NextMoveEvent`, instead of calling `Board.NextMove()` directly. Then, have the board keep calling `MakeMove()` on each listener in a loop until an event is returned that has `finished` set.

Answer (score 0):

See State Design pattern, it is  useful for  games http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern
There is a Java example too.